# При нажатии на QPushButton ничего не происходит

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside2

Надо при нажатии на кнопку открыть word-файл.

Но когда нажимаешь, ничего не происходит. Ошибку в консоль не выводит

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from ui import Ui_Form


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

Form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

def bp():
    open("E:/GUI/1.docx")

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы делаете и что у вас не получается. И опубликуйте то, что у вас есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile), чтобы открыть файл ассоциированной с ним программой.

А функция `open` используется для работы с содержимым файлов: считывания, записи, добавления и `open("E:/GUI/1.docx")` сделает открытие файла. Кст, чтобы считать этот формат нужно сделать так: `print(open("E:/GUI/1.docx", 'rb').read())`

Пример с [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile):

```
import os
import sys

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from ui import Ui_Form

#Create application

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create form and unit UI

Form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

#Hook logic

def bp():
    os.startfile("E:/GUI/1.docx")

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect ( bp )

#Run main loop

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, уже не знал, что делать.

Comment: @Intelligent, кст, в qt есть аналогичный метод https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать `PyQt5`, то вашу задача может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog, 
                             QMessageBox, QApplication)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Document Word.Application')
        self.axWidget = QAxWidget(self)

        self.buttonOpen = QPushButton('Open', self)
        self.buttonOpen.clicked.connect(self.handleOpen)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.axWidget)   
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonOpen) 

    def handleOpen(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Выберите файл word', '', 'word(*.docx *.doc)')
        if not path:
            return

        return self.openOffice(path, 'Word.Application')   

    def openOffice(self, path, app):
        self.axWidget.clear()
        if not self.axWidget.setControl(app):
            return QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка', 'Нет установки  %s' % app)
        self.axWidget.dynamicCall(
            'SetVisible (bool Visible)', 'false')         
        self.axWidget.setProperty('DisplayAlerts', False)
        self.axWidget.setControl(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(840, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку "from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget
ImportError: DLL load failed: "